# Как сдампить куки через pickle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookie, dump

Хочу через `pickle` сдампить куки.

Подскажите как это сделать?

```
import browser_cookie3
cookies = browser_cookie3.chrome()
r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com', cookies=cj)
```

Comment: Вы хотите их куда-то сохранить?

Comment: А так, судя по коду в той либе https://github.com/borisbabic/browser_cookie3/blob/master/__init__.py#L249, `.chrome()` вернет объект https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#http.cookiejar.CookieJar А вот что с этим объектом можно сделать нужно подумать. Вроде бы, у него видел метод `save`

Comment: @gil9red сохранить в куки-jar

Answer (score 0):

Используй `requests.Session` вместо функций-врапперов, чтобы иметь доступ к cookie jar.

```
import pickle
import requests


if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = requests.session()
    session.get('http://stackoverflow.com')

    # запись
    with open('cookies.pkl', 'wb') as fp:
        pickle.dump(session.cookies, fp)

    # чтение
    with open('cookies.pkl', 'rb') as fp:
        session.cookies.update(pickle.load(fp))
```